# What is 'value' in this Uniswap transaction log on Etherscan?

Tags: ether, etherscan, proof-of-stake

[image]

Hi, I'm finding it difficult to understand what Value is(=0.16 ETH in this example).
Is it the miner tip to put the transaction first wrt to everyone else? Or is it the value in ETH of the token swapped plus the gas fee? Does the new ETH update only allow for gas amount to be sent as a first-price sealed-bid auction? I really have no idea I'm not very knowledgeable on this matter and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the value (in terms of ether) of the amount of tokens or ether that was transferred from the wallet during the transaction. The gas is separately stated below.

Also I think that banana gun protocol was recently hacked or a bug was discovered or something...Id stay away from it.

Comment: mmm but the amount of tokens times the price doens't give me that value in ether/usd. I won't use Bananagun i'm just trying to wrap my head around it.